# We need to change the timeline status of the post

Tags: php, facebook, curl, post, timeline

We are trying to change the timeline status of the post by  posting the parameter

```
timeline_visibility=hidden
```

Here is our curl request:

```
curl -F "timeline_visibility=hidden" "https://graph.facebook.com/456270648352201/?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&debug=all"
```

> We are getting following response from the Facebook API "message":
>   "(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action",

Any guess why this error is happening?

Please help us with that. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Because that is a photo, not a post - and photos don’t have that field.

Comment: ok..weather its a photo or video..but, in the end, its a post. shouldn't the timeline_visibility applicable for the same?

Comment: _“but, in the end, its a post”_ - no, not in Facebook terms. A post is a post, a photo is a photo, and a video is a video. They all have their own documentation for a reason.

Comment: Ok..can't we just upload a photo via post API? like $data = [
                                          'message' => $caption,
                                          'source' => $fb->fileToUpload($finalpath),
                                          'timeline_visibility'=>$is_hidden
                                        ];
$response = $fb->post('/PAGE_ID/post', $data,ACCESS_TOKEN);

Comment: @04FS ....I just solved the problem by using the no_story parameter..Thanks for the enlightenment :)